# How to add badge to file or folder with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

How to add badge to file or folder with AppleScript? I found some approach at  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1881786?start=0&tstart=0 but I don't think it is actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my helper program [SetFileIcon here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/SetFileIcon/SetFileIcon.html), and at the bottom of the web page is an example applescript showing how to use it.

Comment: Can you release this code under BSD/GPLv3? we need it in http://sparkleshare.org project

Comment: Can it be implemented in C#/Mono?

Comment: @Darvin: You can use it as-is. I state that at the top of the web page. So just download the code/executable and incorporate it however you like. It uses Apple API's, so you won't be able to use it in Mono unless there's some mechanism to link to them.